# How to deleting a Text from anchorpane in javafx

Tags: fxml

I am new to the Java fxml.

I' m using anchor pane and adding 30 text,

Then i want to delete one text out of 30.

I have done it in javafx code , how to do with fxml.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've added 30 TextField or Labels to your AnchorPane.  If so, the process to remove one is fairly straightforward.  You need to give the AnchorPane and the child that you want to remove fx:id attributes and then in your Controller, create matching declarations for each of them.

Once you've done that, you can remove the TextField or Label from the AnchorPane using the same JavaFX code as before.  I assume there is a trigger for removing this field, so that's the right place to remove the Text.

For example:

```
<AnchorPane id="myAnchor" ...>
  <TextField id="myText" ...>
```

And in your controller:

```java
@FXML AnchorPane myAnchor;
@FXML TextField myText;
...
myAnchor.remove(myText);
```